The logarithm map on the Lubin-Tate formal group to the additive group.
I have been trying to understand section II.2.1. of the Geometrization of the local Langlands correspondence by Fargues and Scholze.  I will transcribe the relevant part here.
Up to isomorphism, there is a unique 1-dimensional formal group $G$ over $\mathcal{O}_{\breve{E}}$ with action by $\mathcal{O}_E$, such that the two induced actions on Lie $G$ coincide; this is "the" Lubin-Tate formal group $G=G_{\mathrm{LT}}$ of $E$. Fixing a uniformizer $\pi \in E$, we normalize this as follows. First, any LubinTate formal group law over $\mathcal{O}_E$ is the unique (up to unique isomorphism) lift of a 1-dimensional formal group over $k$ whose Lie algebra has the correct $\mathcal{O}_E$-action. Now, if $E$ is $p$-adic then $G_k$ is classified by Dieudonné theory by a finite projective $W_{\mathcal{O}_E}(k)$-module $M$ equipped with a $\sigma$-linear isomorphism $F: M\left[\frac{1}{\pi}\right] \cong M\left[\frac{1}{\pi}\right]$ such that $M \subset F(M) \subset \frac{1}{\pi} M .{ }^2$ Here, we take $M=W_{\mathcal{O}_E}(k)$ with $F=\frac{1}{\pi} \sigma$. One can similarly define $G$ in equal characteristic, but actually we will explain a different way to pin down the choice just below; under our normalization, $G$ is already defined over $\mathcal{O}_E$.
After passing to the generic fibre, $G_E$ is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb{G}_a$, compatibly with the $\mathcal{O}_E$-action, and one can choose a coordinate on $G \cong \operatorname{Spf} \mathcal{O}_E [[ X ]]$ so that explicitly, the logarithm map is given by
$$
\log _G: G_E \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_{a, E}: X \mapsto X+\frac{1}{\pi} X^q+\frac{1}{\pi^2} X^{q^2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{\pi^n} X^{q^n}+\ldots
$$
Regarding the convergence of $\log _G$, we note that in fact it defines a map of rigid-analytic varieties (i.e. adic spaces locally of finite type over $E$ )
$$
\log _G: G_E^{\mathrm{ad}} \cong \mathbb{D}_E \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_{a, E}^{\mathrm{ad}}
$$
from the open unit disc
$$
G_E^{\mathrm{ad}} \cong \operatorname{Spa} \mathcal{O}_E [[ X ]]\times_{\mathrm{Spa}\mathcal{O}_E}  \operatorname{Spa} E
$$
to the adic space corresponding to $\mathbb{G}_a$. From the formula, one sees that in small enough discs it defines an isomorphism, and via rescaling by powers of $\pi$ (which on the level of $G_E^{\text {ad }}$ defines finite étale covers of degree $q$, while it is an isomorphism on $\mathbb{G}_{a, E}^{\text {ad }}$ ), one sees that one has an exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow G_E^{\mathrm{ad}}\left[\pi^{\infty}\right] \rightarrow G_E^{\mathrm{ad}} \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_{a, E}^{\mathrm{ad}} \rightarrow 0
$$
on the big étale site of adic spaces over $\operatorname{Spa} E$, where $G_E^{\text {ad }}\left[\pi^{\infty}\right] \subset G_E^{\text {ad }}$ is the torsion subgroup. This is, in fact, the generic fibre of $G\left[\pi^{\infty}\right]=\bigcup_n G\left[\pi^n\right]$ over $\operatorname{Spa} \mathcal{O}_E$, and each $G\left[\pi^n\right]=\operatorname{Spa} A_n$ is represented by some finite $\mathcal{O}_E$-algebra $A_n$ of degree $q^n$. Inductively, $G\left[\pi^{n-1}\right] \subset G\left[\pi^n\right]$ giving a map $A_n \rightarrow A_{n-1}$; after inverting $\pi$, this is split, and the other factor is a totally ramified extension $E_n \mid E$. Then
$$
G_E^{\mathrm{ad}}\left[\pi^{\infty}\right]=\bigcup_n \operatorname{Spa} A_n\left[\frac{1}{\pi}\right]=\bigsqcup_n \operatorname{Spa} E_n .
$$
I have a few questions,

How exactly does $\log _G: G_E \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_{a, E}: X \mapsto X+\frac{1}{\pi} X^q+\frac{1}{\pi^2} X^{q^2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{\pi^n} X^{q^n}+\ldots $ land in $\mathbb{G}_{a, E}$ since this is a formal power series and elements in $\mathbb{G}_{a, E}$ are just polynomials.

How exactly does one understand this map of corresponding rigid analytic varieties. I do not quite understand the argument about isomorphism on small enough discs and rescalling.



Maybe at the beginning of the transcription you can recall what $E$ is in the context?
